# Implement continuous date-time labels on x-axis of mpandroidchart

Tags: android, datetime, axis-labels, mpandroidchart

We collect data points at various days throughout the year and want to display them in a chart - the x-axis showing the date.

Right now we create an array of length 364 each containing the value for the corresponding day.
However, we want the x-axis to not display the day of the year but rather years, months or days depending on the scale that the use changes with a zoom gesture.

When looking at data for the entire year the axis should show jan - feb ... - nov - dec but when pinching in (thereby causing the the axis to rescale) to show only feb .. mar and individual days of the months.

Is this possible?

---

In order to improve the question - some images:
Say we start with the graph showing years:
[image: example1]

Now we zoom in the x-axis to change the scale - x-axis labeling should change again and depict some days of the months and eventually all days:
[image: example2]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and sorry about that. I added some pictures to the questions to improve it.. hope that helps.

Comment: Good question, I also want that functionality. @philipp-jahoda could you please respond?

Comment: I need similar functionality too.

Comment: Did you guys figure something out?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can be done quite easily. There is an example in the MpAndroidChart repository [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/e5b66192e7b303d7d25fc172b1878c055b554047/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/custom/DayAxisValueFormatter.java). Basically you create a custom AxisValueFormatter class that extends ValueFormatter, pass in the chart object, then when getFormattedValue is called you can call `chart.getVisibleXRange` to check the zoom level and decide exactly what you want to display on the x-axis labels.

Comment: There's nothing in the example about what format the value passed in should be. I'm passing in kotlin Date().time.toFloat()... but it just kills the app.